# JComboBox will display first item in array, but throws an Exception when selecting second item

Tags: java, swing, exception, jcombobox

I can switch order of filenames "dr.png" or "MF4040.png" and it will default as it is supposed to do, code compiles, runs and ALWAYS works while displaying the first item in the array, but will throw an exception when the second item is selected in the `JComboBox` when the program is running. Also I am using JDK1.6 and Eclipse 4.2. Source is from Bucky's JAVA tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XS4-5GmRnp8&index=69&list=PL484D73FA74A11AC9

Here is the code...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gui extends JFrame{

private JComboBox box;
private JLabel picture;

private static String[] filename = {"dr.png", "MF4040.png" };
private Icon[] pics = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0]))};

public gui(){
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    box = new JComboBox(filename);

    box.addItemListener(
        new ItemListener(){             
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);

             }
         }      
);

    add(box);
    picture=new JLabel(pics[0]);

     add(picture);

}
}
```

AND MY MAIN...

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class apples {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    gui go = new gui();
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setSize(300,200);
    go.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Here are the exceptions that get thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
     at gui$1.itemStateChanged(gui.java:24)
     at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1205)
     at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1262)
     at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1309)
     at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:100)
     at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:88)
     at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:557)
     at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:603)
     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:831)
     at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:273)
     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
     at com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxPopup$1.processMouseEvent(AquaComboBoxPopup.java:132)
     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
     at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
     at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
     at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seting the second icon:

```
private Icon[] pics = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0]))};
```

Solve it replacing with this:

```
private Icon[] pics = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0])), 
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[1]))};
```